# Convert Hex string to Image

Tags: c#, arrays, image, hex, byte

I am using FormsConnect an App for the iPad to export signatures to XML.
The output from the App is as follows:

```
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
```

Now I'm trying to convert this Hex string back into an image using this code:

```
 Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(StringToByteArray(hex)));
 
 public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Substring(2, hex.Length - 2);
        if (hex.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hex));
        }

        byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
       
        for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
        {
            string byteValue = hex.Substring(index * 2, 2);
            HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return HexAsBytes;
    }
```

But I keep getting Parameter is not valid, when attempting to Load the stream into a Bitmap. I posed the question to the developer of the App, and here is his response:

> Dear Alex
>
> The data is stored in binary, hex format. Here are the instructions on how to read the binary data and write it back out as a jpg.
>
> byteData[i] = (digit [i * 2] shl 4) + (digit [i * 2 + 1])
>
> The above assumes that the digits are already converted to numbers from 0 to 15.  If you’re trying to optimize your script by writing to memory in larger chunks (integers, for instance) you need to take endianness into account.  All major CPU architectures are little-endian which means the numbers are stored with their bytes arranged in the opposite order from their actual value (ie, 0x1234 is stored as 0x3412 in memory).
>
> Below are two different scripts for extracting blob data from the form:

```
 1. Python Script:
iterate over each photo attached to image field in FormConnect xml file
data = R[i]

to strip '0x' off front of each blob
a = data[2:]
iterate over each byte, write as binary int to array
for i in range(len(a)/2):
                b = (int(bin(int(a[i*2],16)),2)<<4) + int(bin(int(a[i*2+1],16)),2)
                data.append(b)
 write array to binary file

F = file(outFile,'wb')
data.tofile(F)
F.close()


PHP Script:
$pic = "";
$field = substr($field,2);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
$pic = pack("H*", $field);
echo $pic;
```

If anyone can help me on this, I would be very grateful.
Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: I converted given hex string into byte array, and saved it to a file. My image viewer does not recognize this file.

Comment: Given array has the length of 4,381 bytes. Because length is odd number the array cannot be adjusted for endianess. And as Gabe said, this is not a valid jpg file in any endianess. There's no `FF D8 FF E0` header, nor JFIF after the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't the hex conversion routine, it's that the original data isn't encoded properly. Based on all the zeroes within it, I'd say it's just a raw bitmap! My guess is that the author of the program that generated that data forgot to encode the bitmap into a specific file format before outputting it.

Comment: Thanks to Gabe and Dialecticus, an update on the App has resolved this issue.